# Testing a pseudo-RESTful api using node.js

Tags: json, node.js, rest, zend-framework, functional-testing

I need a library that is able to simulate a browser (in that it persists cookies and session id values as a browser would) while simultaneously giving me access to the JSON strings the server returns. I need it to ignore redirects and such as well.

Is there such a tool that would allow me to use node.js and Jasmine for testing a pseudo-RESTful api?

Note: I am migrating an ancient api written in Zend 1.8 to a new api that conforms more to RESTful practices, but in doing so, I must ensure that the new api is not so different from the old that it simply does not function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postman, this is a chrome plugin.

[Postman Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to deal with the GUI side of things, simple command line `curl` should work. It can use cookies, take text input via command line, return the results from the server as simple text.

You do say in your question test using node.js... not sure why you would feel that you 'have' to use that to test your api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jmeter which is open source and has user friendly GUI. You do not need any special tools.
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RESTSampler/